# Entity Framework, Error while use Groupby

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by

I have 2 tables, `Good`:

```
class Good
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrderPoint { get; set; }
    public int? GoodGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual GoodGroup GoodGroup { get; set; }
}
```

and `GoodGroup`:

```
class GoodGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to know count of goods in each `GoodGroupName` with this code:

```
var res = db.Goods
            .GroupBy(r => r.GoodGroupId)
            .Select(m => new 
                         {
                             m.Name,
                             m.Count(s => s.Id)
                         })
            .ToList();
```

But the query doesn't find `m.Name`; anybody know what my mistake is?

Comment: Well the result of `GroupBy` is a sequence of *groups*. A group doesn't have a name. It has a key, which in this case would be the `GoodGroupId`. There's nothing in what you've shown to suggest that every `GoodGroup` with the same ID would have the same name - so what would you expect the "name" of the group to be?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to know Count of goods in each GoodGroupName

Comment: So either group by GoodGroupName as well as GoodGroupId, or look the names up later.

Comment: You're going to have to do a join if you want the name from the `GoodGroup` table.

Comment: @juharr is it not enough that i have `public virtual GoodGroup GoodGroup { get; set; }`  code in table Good for join? I think its put relation automatically..

Comment: @combo_ci Yes, a navigation property will act as a join.  So instead of grouping on `GoodGrouId` you should be able to group on `GoodGroup` then in you're select `m.Key.Name` should be what you want.  If `GoodGroup` is properly setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have a true entity-framework one-to-many relation ship: a GoodGroup has zero or more Goods, every Good belongs to exactly one GoodGroup.

If you design your [one-to-many according to the entity framework guidelines,](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) your query would be much simpler

```
class GoodGroup
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  // no need for attribute, automatically primary key

    // a GoodGroup has zero or more Goods:
    public virtual ICollection<Good> Goods {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

class Good
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     // every good belongs to exactly one GoodGroup using foreign key
     public int GoodGroupId {get; set;}
     public virtual GoodGroup GoudGroup {get; set;}

     ... // other properties
}
```

If you stick to the [entity framework code-first conventions,](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) then this is all that entity frame needs to know to detect that you want do configure a one-to-many relationship. If you want to use different class names or properties, you'll have to use attributes or fluent API.

Because I've added the ICollection of Goods to each GoodGroup, you won't need to do a GroupBy:

```
var result = myDbContext.GoodGroups.Select(goodGroup => new
{
    Name = goodGroup.Name,
    NrOfGroups = goodGroup.Groups.Count(),
});
```

Entity framework is smart enough to detect that for the Count() a SQL inner join and a Group By and Count are needed.

Comment: Thanks, is there exist a problem if I dont put `public virtual ICollection<Good> Goods {get; set;}` in `GoodGroup`?

Comment: I think the result query must be `NrOfGroups = goodGroup.Goods.Count(),` instead of `NrOfGroups = goodGroup.Groups.Count(),`

Answer (score 1):

Because the `GroupBy` method return `[IGrouping][1]` interface which has "Key" property and it has inherited from `IEnumerable` interface. 
You must write the code like this.

```
//Result Type: List<IEnumerable<GoodGroup>>
var res = db.Goods
                .GroupBy(r => r.GoodGroupId)
                .Select(grp => grp
                    .Select(m => new GoodGroup
                    {
                        Id = m.Id,
                        Name = m.Name,
                        Code = m.Code
                    }))
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get "Count" then you can use this part of code:

```
var res = db.Goods
                .GroupBy(r => r.GoodGroupId)
                .Select(grp => new 
                {
                    Name = grp.First().Name,
                    Count = grp.Count()
                })
                .ToList();
```